# Finding the basis and dimension of $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{im} T$ for a linear map of polynomials with different degrees

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T\colon V\to U$ be a linear map.
>
> Let $V=\Bbb R_3[x] \\U=\Bbb R_2[x]  \\ 
> T(\mathcal P(x))=(x\mathcal P(x))''$
>
> Find the basis and dimension of $\ker(T)$ and $\operatorname{im}(T)$ for the linear map.
>
> Determine if it's an injection or surjection.

Trying to find the kernel I did:

$T:(p(x))=(0) \Rightarrow (xp(x))''=(0)  $

That means that all $p(x)=0$ (is it ?)

So the basis is just the simple form of the polynomial of second degree: $x^2+x=0$ and  $dim(ker(T))=1$ because all of the polynomials equal 0 (not sure).

About the image, we know that $\{e_i\} \, , \, \operatorname{im}(T) = \operatorname{span}\{T(e_i)  \}$ But i don't know how to apply it in this case.

Please share your thoughts on how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\mathcal P$? What is $p$? What is meant by $\{e_i\} \, , \, \operatorname{im}(T)$?

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$T(\mathcal P(x))=(x\mathcal P(x))''=0\iff\deg (x\mathcal P(x))\leq 1\iff \mathcal P(x)=C$$
hence
$$\ker T=\mathbb R_0[x]\quad;\quad\dim\ker T=1$$
hence by the rank-nullity theorem $\dim\operatorname{im} T=4-1=3$ and it's simple to see that $\deg(T(\mathcal P(x)))\le2$ hence 
$$\operatorname{im} T=\mathbb R_2[x]$$
Now we can see easily that $T$ isn't injective neither surjective.